# Rename Multiple folder in a directory with python

Tags: python

I want to automate renaming multiple folders in a folder using python. This is the code i use:

```
import os

path = r"C:/Users/Dimas hermanto/Documents/Data science gadungan/Belajar python/Computer vision and     
Deep learning/Flask tutorial 2/stanford-dogs-dataset/test"

directory_list = os.listdir(path)




for filename in directory_list:
    src = filename
    dst = filename[filename.find('-') + 1:]

    # print(dst)

    os.rename(src, dst)

print("File renamed!")
```

This is the name format of the folders i want to rename:

[image]

What i'm trying to do is slice the filename string so it'll only came out as

```
Chihuahua 
Japanese_spaniel, 
Maltese_dog,
Pekinese, 
Shih_tzu, 
etc.
```

But when i run the code, it returns:

```
Exception has occurred: FileNotFoundError
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'n02085620-Chihuahua' -> 'Chihuahua'
```

What should i do to fix this ? When i try to print the `dst` variable, it return the list of desired target names. So i assume that i already set the right folder path

Comment: The `listdir` is giving the file names in the path, but the program is being run from a different directory. The code supplies only then name, so it's using the current directory as the path, where no such name exists.

Comment: So... i need to run the program in the same directory as the folders i want to rename ?

Comment: You need to add the path prefix back in. `os.path.join`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The src and dst aren't the absolute path, so it's trying to rename a file from the directory of the python script.

You should be able to fix this just by replacing `os.rename(src, dst)` with `os.rename(os.path.join(path, src), os.path.join(path, dst))` to specify absolute path.